# Get contents between two parameters , parameters occurs multiple time in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, sh

Using awk or sed, how to get contents between two parameters , parameters occurs multiple time in a file

For instance, file contents

```
Entering AAA
12
Entering BBB
13
Leaving AAA
14
Leaving AAA
15
Leaving AAA
16
Leaving BBB
```

Currently I am using

```
cat 1.txt |sed -n '/Entering AAA/,/Leaving AAA/ p'
```

with this , I am getting contents between first occurrence of "Entering AAA" and first occurrence of "Leaving AAA"
ie

```
Entering AAA
12
Entering BBB
13
Leaving AAA
```

But , I want contents from **first occurrence** of "Entering AAA" to **last occurrence** of "Leaving AAA"

**Expected output :**

```
Entering AAA
12
Entering BBB
13
Leaving AAA
14
Leaving AAA
15
Leaving AAA
```

Kindly help.

Comment: could be there multiple lines with `Entering AAA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **`tac`** + **`awk`** trick:

```
tac file | awk '/Leaving AAA/,/Entering AAA/' | tac
```

The output:

```
Entering AAA
12
Entering BBB
13
Leaving AAA
14
Leaving AAA
15
Leaving AAA
```

Comment: That just reverses the problem as it'll get the text starting from the **last** occurrence of Entering AAA, not from the first as the OP requested - `I want contents from first occurrence of "Entering AAA" to last occurrence of "Leaving AAA"`. The OPs posted sample input just isn't adequate to show the difference.

Comment: @EdMorton, see my comment under the question

Answer (score 5):

In any awk using a 2-pass approach:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/Leaving AAA/) end=NR; next} /Entering AAA/{f=1} f; FNR==end{exit}' file file
Entering AAA
12
Entering BBB
13
Leaving AAA
14
Leaving AAA
15
Leaving AAA
```

Alternatively doing it in one pass with GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='Entering AAA.*Leaving AAA' 'RT{print RT}' file
Entering AAA
12
Entering BBB
13
Leaving AAA
14
Leaving AAA
15
Leaving AAA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using `perl` to get this done in a single pass in slurp mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?ms).*?(^Entering AAA.*Leaving AAA\R*).*/$1/' file

Entering AAA
12
Entering BBB
13
Leaving AAA
14
Leaving AAA
15
Leaving AAA
```

- `.*` is a greedy pattern that ensures to match longest string between start and end patterns.
- `(?ms)` enables `MULTILINE` and `DOTALL` modes for this regex

You may also use a back-reference:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?ms).*?(^Entering (AAA).*Leaving \2\R*).*/$1/' file
```